# odd alignment within spans/div

Tags: html, css

I have a span that contains text as well as an input field. I was wondering if it would be possible to have the text align to the left and the input field align to the right.

```
<span class="textBox">NAME: <input type="text" id="NAME"/></span>

.textBox{
    display:inline-block;
    width:450px
}
```

first an example of my span then the current CSS style for it.

Comment: add `float:right` to the input?

Comment: Just a tip -- you might wrap the label in `label` tags with a `for` attribute since the inputs won't be right next to one another... Just an accessibility tip. Like http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/Ju7C6/

Comment: @brbcoding Not entirely my code I was planning on doing that. This is the first of a series of clean up steps I am taking.

Comment: @Jinjubei oh alright... Just wanted to point it out in case you weren't aware.

Comment: @brbcoding I would even take it a step further and get rid of the `<span>` and the `for`-attribute becomes optional: http://jsfiddle.net/tAY6M/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text will be aligned to the left by default, so you could just float the input to the right:

```
.textBox input{
    float:right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7788v/)

Or, should you prefer to use positioning instead of floating:

```
.textBox input{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Remember that the parent will need a position that isn't the default:

```
.textBox{
    display:inline-block;
    width:450px;
    position:relative;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7788v/2)

Comment: +1 for having both ways using `float` and an example with `position`.

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypeY7/)

```
.textBox{
    display:inline-block;
    width:450px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#eee;
    overflow:auto;
}

.textBox input{
    float:right;
}
```

Add float right to push to right and `overflow:auto` to container to get clear the float

[image]

Comment: Positioning would be a better way than floating.

Comment: and why would that be ? considering that each of the textboxes will have to be positioned relative ?

Comment: Because almost every designer is abusing the `float` property like you do. Float is for images in texts. Why you think there is a `clear-fix` needed when floating? Still your example does suit for this question and I know it works, this is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult .

Consider this :

**HTML:**

```
<span class="textBox">NAME: 
    <input type="text"class='text1' id="NAME"/>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.textBox{
    display:inline-block;
    width:450px;

}

.text1{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Find the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/TbB3S/

You just had to give `float:left` to your input text.

Comment: Don't think this is what OP is looking for... They want it the other way around.

Comment: @brbcoding : Ohh, could not fathom that from the question asked .